# Low hashrate on some CPU instances

Tags: cpu-mining, hashrate, vps

I have currently 30 CPU instances running minerd on Ubuntu (for XMR). Not all instances have the same CPU, but some of the instances have "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650L v4 @ 1.70GHz". These instances are all rented Cloud Servers (VPS).

Now these instances give 30+ H/s each on average. Most of the instances can perform at 30 H/s consistently. But some instances which have exactly the same setup and CPU run at a much lower hashrate and perform at only 3 H/s.

What things can I check and how can setup these other instances to also make 30+ H/s? 30+ H/s per instance is profitable. 3 H/s is not profitable at all. Any ideas/suggestions?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 2):

The difference is likely the availability of AES-NI:

`grep aes /proc/cpuinfo`

Some VM configurations may not allow use of the underlying AES-NI instructions by VMs.

Less likely, it could be the lack of L3 cache memory (Cryptonight needs 2 MB cache per mining thread for good performance).

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is not correct. All instances show that they support AES-NI. Actually the hash rate fluctuates. Sometimes it reaches 30 H/s, but most of the time it only achieves 3 H/s.

Comment: For such a huge difference... I don't suppose the 3 H/s ones are running heavy duty software at the same time ? :) Might be hard to tell if it's a VM and you don't have access to the host though.

Comment: Yes. That sort of what I am thinking as well. For me I am only running the mining sw on these instances. Of course I have no influence on what else is running on the same CPU core (as it is a VM).